# Encoding issue in excel

Tags: excel, encoding, power-automate

As mentioned in the title I have an encoding issue in Excel. It requires special characters and also some letters.
I will show you an example: 1st being a good one and 2nd a bad one.
1st example
[image]

After I refresh the Excel workbook my special characters become something like the following.
2nd example
[image]

Sadly my work around right now is, using one of my colleagues Mac, to go in and refresh the workbook again and the special characters get fixed.

These Excel workbooks are created by a Microsoft Power Automate flow, and checking every excel file he creates in order to fix this issue, is waste of time.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to fix this.

Sincerely, Daniel

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the Excel files yourself via a Power Automate flow you could look into using the Byte Order Mark characters to the beginning of the file.

Below is an explanation how you could achieve that:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-a-csv-file-that-uses-UTF-8-character-encoding/m-p/1311587/highlight/true#M148980

Comment: Hello Expiscornovus, 
Thank you for your reply. I am not creating the excel files, but updating an existing 'Master' Excel file (with new data) and then save it as new file. I want to mention that in the 'Master' file the special characters exist, it is after I update it through a power automate desktop flow, it changes the special characters.
I will try to implement your solution.
Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Thanks for sharing more details about your setup. It is also good to know that your are using a desktop flow (RPA) and not a cloud flow. That makes a huge difference :D Let me have another look at this and see if I can 1. reproduce and 2. find a solution.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue (with Windows and PAD 2.25.00182.22280). I used the Launch Excel and Save Excel steps. In the Save Excel I used the Save mode: save document as and the Excel Workbook (.xlsx) format. Can you share a screenshot of the steps and the configuration you are using in PAD?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]
This is exactly what my PAD is doing. There is a master excel file, and when the online flow finds a new row in the database is running this PAD flow.
After few refreshes the new data is updated in the excel file, and that is when the special characters get changed, like presented in the main post

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).